# How to get only public video using FQL or graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-fql

I need to get all public videos from an particular user account. I have a valid default access token. But it doesn't return anything when I request videos using FQL or graphAPI.

SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=

FB document says that I can get publicly available videos by any valid access token.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/

Any valid access_token for publicly available videos

I used facebook explorer tool test this but it is not working for me.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Please let me know if I do anything wrong. I just need to get public videos from user profile. I can use user_videos permission to get both public and private videos. But there is no flag to identify that whether the particular video is public or private.

Please help me on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Malligairajan G.

Comment: Do anyone have answer to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

go to [the explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and do  the sample query code that they give you, which is as follows:

```
SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=20531316728
```

Before doing the query, you have to press the button "get access token". I checked user_videos in the authorization, but maybe it is not required. After you get the access token, press the button "FQL query" (not Graph Api), insert the query above, press submit.
This is the result I get (first result. the whole thing is too long):

```
 {
  "data": [
    {
      "vid": "10200156550214780", 
      "owner": 20531316728, 
      "title": "Building Graph Search", 
      "description": "Learn about the design and engineering behind Graph Search (http://fb.com/graphsearch).", 
      "thumbnail_link": "https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-prn1/632230_10200156572295332_10200156550214780_21792_636_t.jpg", 
      "embed_html": "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/video/embed?video_id=10200156550214780\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", 
      "updated_time": 1358280001, 
      "created_time": 1358280001
    },
```

both the graph api and your app won't work if you don't authorize with user_videos permissions. In other words you need an authorization even to fetch public data.

Comment: This works for the owner id which you supplied. But when I use my owner id 100002749491490 it is not working. I have public videos in my profile. Wondering what could be the issue??

Comment: also, you should use your profile id number. The id you provide is too long to be a facebook id. Have you checked? Just replace gra.facebook.com after having visited your profile. You should get your id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Did you authorize your app with user_videos permission? In this case it returns all videos including non public videos. But I am not able to segregate public and non public videos. That is why I try to get public videos with default access token.

Comment: yes I was editing the answer because I have located you (apologies) and have found that you do have a public video that doesn't show up in queries. So I tried this on myself and set a video public. Both the graph api explorer and your own app will return nothing if you don't authorize them, for user_videos. It doesn't matter if the video is public. Weird but true. You can try with my own id (i have left a video public for now): 1351681723. It does nothing if I don't authorize the explorer or the app. If I do, the query will return the whole collection of videos, public and private.

Comment: I can see a video for your ID, So I guess you have authorized App explorer with user_videos permission. So it returns all public and non-public video. Another observation here, if you pass the facebook page id as owner id then it returns all public videos. It has problem with user id only.

Comment: yes, indeed. Pages are a different thing they're public by default. (Otherwise they have no sense). Anyhow, this is all I can do. Kindly accept the answer or if not satisfied ask someone else...

Answer (score 0):

try this FQL query:

```
{"SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner== me()" }
```